# java plugin on email for lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I am new to IBM Lotus Notes. We had a requirement where below things are to be done:

1. we have to create a button which will be visible when forward/reply/new mail is clicked.
2. We have to write a even for this button.
3. After clicking on this button the current opened mail should be saved in the local drive.
4. And after that should call a custom DLL where the other functionality is implemented.

I am a java developer. Please advice me can we achieve using the java knowledge by developing any custom plugin and invoking that using lotus script.
Is there any approach which we can look into?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

For (1) and (2), you have to modify the default Notes Mail Template (add the button and the code) using the Domino Designer and roll it out to all users (consult with your local Notes Admin and Developer).

The code (req. 2) executed by the button (req. 1) is usually written in either Lotus Notes Formula Language or Lotusscript, depending on the requirements. Taking your req. 4 into account, that should be Lotusscript.

Req. 3: In what format? RichText, EML, doc, ...? Google provides several solutions for that.

Regarding Requirement 4, see Julian's blog entry [Learning How to Call the Notes API from LotusScript](http://www.nsftools.com/blog/blog-06-2003.htm#06-16-03)

I would not recommend to implement the functionality in Java and call it via LS2J, as this "solution" has quite a few pitfalls (You can only pass primitive data types to a Java function from LS, memory management issues, etc.).

AFAIK this is not doable as a "Sidebar Plugin" to Notes.

Comment: No need to update template if such requirement is solved by sidebar plugin. What makes you think it is not doable?

Comment: Frantisek, the requirement regarding the button to be visible during replies,... Of course, if the requirement would be "drag the mail to the sidebar, save it and run a dll", that would absolutely be doable.